# Problem with the Vuetify Playground not rendering v-app-bar correctly

Tags: vuetify.js

I have another problem that I wanted to ask, so I decided to replicate it in the Vuetify Playground, and it seems like the Playground is having an interesting issue where v-app-bars don't obey the containers they're a part of. For example, I just copied the code verbatim from https://vuetifyjs.com/en/components/app-bars/#density into the Playground, and it looks like this:

[example Vuetify Playground output with misbehaving VAppBar](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kiOqO.png)

[Link to playground](https://play.vuetifyjs.com/#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).

I'd expected the Vuetify Playground to show the same behavior as the Vuetify documentation's sample code (where the app bar obeys the constraints of the containing v-card, but instead I'm getting the results I show above.

Comment: The playground is the correct **default** behavior where appbars are normally fixed to the top of the screen and take up 100% view width.  The documentation examples are mocking applications as if they were embedded on the page.  Obviously, the appbars can not be given their default functionality or they couldn't be propertly displayed in the examples, so for display purposes the example appbars use the `absolute` prop in order to be constrained to their containers. This is verified by inspecting the DOM and comparing the `position` property used between the docs and the playground.

Comment: v-app-bar is a [layout component on app-level](https://vuetifyjs.com/en/features/application-layout/), in cards, use [v-toolbar](https://vuetifyjs.com/en/components/toolbars/), as in [this example](https://vuetifyjs.com/en/components/cards/#content-wrapping)